# I need help in meeting a certain criteria for a function in C#

Tags: c#, function

Write a function that takes one string argument and returns the string with all the vowels removed.

Comment: Show what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
private string FunctionWithTwoParameters(string name="", int count=0)
{
   if (count > 0)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
      {
         name += name;                    
      }                
   }
   return name;
}
```

Such parameters of the method `(string name="", int count=0)` means that you can call the method with or without parameters

### **A little explanation:**

**"Write a function that Has two parameters.":**

```
FunctionWithTwoParameters(string name="", int count=0)
```

**"Allows somebody to call the function with one argument being a name and the second being a number.":**

`FunctionWithTwoParameters(string name="", int count=0)`

This code allows to assign name and number respectively. Also such signature allows to call method with or without parameters.

**"The function returns a string with the name repeated the number of times stated.":**

```
if (count > 0)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
      {
         name += name;                    
      }                
   }
   return name;
```

The body of this method checks whether the number is positive value and if yes, then repeat the number of times stated

Comment: " I just need to know HOW to meet this criteria, not the actual fully completed solution. "

Comment: @DieterB "The solution would also be greatly appreciated."

Comment: @DieterB please see my edited answer, I hope it has explanation to meet the criteria.

Answer (score 1):

when you call the function you pass your name and the number.
so it's something like that in the main:

```
string a;
string name;
int number;//you decide how to obtain the name and the number
a= function (name, number);
```

then you have to write your function like:

```
public string function(String name, int number){ }
```

and do stuff into it!

Answer (score 1):

```
 private IEnumerable<string> test2(string name, int number)
 {
  for (int i = 0; i != number; i++)
  {
    yield return name;
  }
 }
```

In this case, maybe try this.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the parameters as `string` and `int`.

```
function PrintName(string name, int count)
```

Then you could use a new `string` to collect the results (by looping `count` times) or the same `string` (by looping `count-1` times), something like this:

```
   String repeatedNames = String.Empty;
   for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
     repeatedNames += name;
   return repeatedNames;
```

Note that a more effective way to build up a text is `StringBuilder`.

Comment: " I just need to know HOW to meet this criteria, not the actual fully completed solution. "

Comment: @DieterB "The solution would also be greatly appreciated."